# Select rows based on column condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I'm trying to retrieve a list of `ResourceGroupName` from my `ResourceGroup` table. The tricky part to me is, `GroupsId` is subset of `ResourceGroupId` (primary key for resource group), which means I want to be able to select all the `ResourceGroupName` if my condition meets `ResourceGroupName = 'A30_1RecourceGrp'` because this resource group has 2 subsets which are `GroupId = '0014e68000000192'` and `GroupId = '0014e6800000001b'` which is the 2 rows shown below.

This is the table that I need to select from:

[image]

And the result I wanted to achieve is

[image]

MY SQL Server knowledge is very limited and I couldn't find a way to write it, I'm stuck at the SQL below and it only shows 1 result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ResourceGroup rg
LEFT JOIN ResourceGroupGroups rgg ON rgg.ResourceGroupId = rg.ResourceGroupId
WHERE rg.ResourceGroupId = '0014e68000000002'
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Update :

`ResourceGroup` table

[image]

`ResourceGroupGroups` table

[image]

Comment: Could you add  ResourceGroup and ResourceGroupGroups tables fields names in your question?

Comment: Can you provide the example of the final output you want?

Comment: If you replace `*` in your final query with `UNIQUE ResourceGroupName`, I believe you will achieve your goal.

Comment: Sql server so try replace * with "distinct ResourceGroupName"

Comment: @FarshidShekari Hi, I've added both the table structures, my bad for missing that out

Comment: @Vasan There is an image on the result I want to achieve

Comment: @TimRoberts I understand I can select all but I need to query depends on the GroupsId value.

Comment: @AvinashReddy I'm trying to select other rows based on GroupsId on the row I selected

Answer (score 0):

You could try using distinct

```
SELECT distinct rrg.ResourceGroupName 
from ResourceGroup rg
LEFT JOIN ResourceGroupGroups rgg ON rgg.ResourceGroupId = rg.ResourceGroupId
WHERE rg.ResourceGroupId = '0014e68000000002'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made wrong join, It should be like below:

```
SELECT ResourceGroupName  
from ResourceGroupGroups rgg 
LEFT JOIN ResourceGroup rg ON rgg.ResourceGroupId = rg.GroupsId and rg.ResourceGroupId = '0014e68000000002'
```